# WPF StatusBar without content isn't visible inside of Dock Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, statusbar, dockpanel

I am learning `WPF` from this book:
[WPF in Action with Visual Studio 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988223)
There is some layouting example using `DockPanel` with `Menu`, `ToolBarTry`, `StatusBar` and `Grid` inside.

I've coded this UI layout by the book:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfSandBox.WikiManager"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Wiki Manager" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem x:Name="File" Header="_File"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="Edit" Header="_Edit"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="Format" Header="_Format"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="Tools" Header="_Tools"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="Help" Header="_Help"/>
        </Menu>

        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button>New</Button>
                <Button>Print</Button>
                <Button>Spell</Button>
                <Button>Check</Button>
                <Button>Options</Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></StatusBar>

        <Grid></Grid>

    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

The problem is, that `StatusBar` is hidden, as it doesn't have any content yet, while in book it's visible on the bottom of `DockPanel`. Maybe the forgot to mention some parameter to be set (this piece of `XAML` is missing in the book because they are making this layout only in designer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting some content(event an empty textblock) to the StatusBar to give it size:

```
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="StatusBar_Control">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <TextBlock Name="StatusBar_TextBlock" Text=""/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```